# Webpage fails in responsiveness in smaller resolutions (only due to text overflow)

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have:

- [webpage](http://sagiavinash.com/projects/ConsultLeap/code)
- [CSS](http://sagiavinash.com/projects/ConsultLeap/css/style.css)
- [JS](http://sagiavinash.com/projects/ConsultLeap/js/scripts.js)
- [responsinator](http://www.responsinator.com/?url=http://sagiavinash.com/projects/ConsultLeap/)

When I open the webpage in desktop resolutions, resizing doesn't mess up the page, but when it comes to mobile browsers (as you can see in the responsinator) with much smaller dimensions (width & height below 500px) there is this problem that text overflows if I decrease the font using @ media queries, it's too small to read. So I used a combination of font-size-reduction, increasing text-container-size and overflow:scroll to the container. but still the text-container is becoming too small in height to be inside the div#block2.

And I have to use a lot of @media queries to a lot of max-widths as messing up occurs at several window.width ranges. So is it normal to use huge number of @media queries or I have to do a drastic change in my code.

So generally what front end developers do to see the responsiveness in smaller devices where block-wrappers and banners behave perfectly as we orchestrate them to be but text and content like images are the main issue.

I am asking for help in both in general and solution specific to this webpage. I have fair bit of knowledge on Jquery, CSS @media queries.

Answer (score 1):

The problem I see with your code is you have max-height set on your text-wrapper.  That's what causes the scrollbar to appear.  In my opinion, when it comes to text responsiveness on mobile, you have to allow for the text to wrap the way it wants to naturally wrap.  Which usually means letting the paragraph get really tall and thin.  It's just kind of something you have to design for when it comes to small screens.

You can use media queries at the major break points; 768, 640, and 480, to reduce text size and padding but like you said it gets hard to read at a certain point.  I wouldn't drop the font-size below 14px to be on the safe side.

I hope that helps out.

Comment: i get your point but my problem is i have a background image to div#block2 so i cant make the height increase drastically otherwise the background-image(it being landscape) will be cropped in left and right that the visible portion will be insignificant and my client wont accept that

thats the reason i used overflow:scroll to see that div#block2's height need not be increased drastically

so can u suggest a solution

Comment: I would work with your designer to hammer out a solution if you're working with one.  If it we're up to me though, I'd move that first paragraph up to the first section of your design and the bottom paragraph into what is now your footer.  That way when the top piece of text gets thin and tall it can just push the image of your plane down how ever far it needs to.  Also, I wouldn't worry about screens under 320px.  They're more headache than it's worth.